# How to use class property as a default parameter in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods, parameters, properties

I want to use class properties as standard (as when the user don't give any data then it has a default value) parameters to the same class methods.

```
class Class:

    def __init__(self):
        self.property = True

    def method(self, parameter = False):
        if not parameter:
            parameter = self.property
        return parameter

c = Class()
print(c.method())
print(c.method("False"))

>>>True
>>>False
```

The code above will work, but it feels messy, is there a more smart and concise way to do so?

Comment: What's wrong with this piece of code? Can you provide more details?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco, it does work, but isn't there a more concise way to get to the same result?

Comment: Do you want each instance to have its own default? You could use a class attribute instead of an instance attribute. Also, `None` would be a more conventional sentinel than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really hard-coding the default in `__init__`, you would be better off (ab)using a class attribute as the default.

```
class Class:
    _param_default = True

    def method(self, parameter=_param_default):
        return parameter

    del _param_default  # Optional, but it's not really a class attribute
```

If this really should have an instance-specific default, you can't really make it any shorter. The method is defined before the instance is created, so you need to make the check at runtime.

```
class Class:

    _sentinel = object()

    def __init__(self):
        self.property = True

    def method(self, parameter=_sentinel):
        if parameter is _sentinel:
            parameter = self.property
        return parameter
```

`None` is the more conventional sentinel, and you can use that in place of `_sentinel` if `None` isn't otherwise a valid argument to `method`.

Comment: It does feels more clean using a class attribute instead of an instance attribute, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest way to do it:

```
class Class:
    property = True
    def method(self, parameter = 0):
        if not parameter:
            parameter = Class().property
        return parameter
print(Class().method())
print(Class().method("False"))
```

Comment: Presumably, the idea is that there are multiple methods that would share the same default, otherwise yes, there's no reason to use an instance attribute in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think at something more concise than this:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.property = True
    def method(self, parameter=0):
        return self.property if not parameter else parameter
```